# Regex to remove parentheses from string?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking to remove the all parentheses from a given string. After some research, I've come to the conclusion that Regex was my best bet. However, looking at it (let alone looking at it, *thinking* about looking at it) gives me a headache. What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Can I ask the reason for the unexplained negative downvote? :) Is this an unclear question? Duplicate? I did some searching and didn't really find anything similar.

Comment: It was maybe because you question is very basic regex and any search does give you an answer for sure.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'any search'. I spent a good bit looking for a solution to stripping parentheses from a string, didn't see one. Although I did see one chap talking about being careful to/not to escape them for some reason, it didn't really make sense. ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I agree with the downvoter's sentiment; your question has no clearly defined problem, no explanation for how you arrived at deciding to use regular expressions, and no example of what your expected output is.  See my answer...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following statement removes all characters `(` and `)`.

```
Regex.Replace("This (is (a) (test.", "[()]", "")   // -> "This is a test."
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, or is very trivial.

Why not use `String.Replace('(', '').Replace(')','')`?

If you must use a regex, this is the link for how you would use a [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Why is this "even worse"? I find this much easier on the eyes than Howard's answer. And I don't think it's slower, so why the negative attitude? Well, except that it won't work with the single quotes, of course...

Comment: @JeffMercado please explain why multiple `String.Replace()` calls is "even worse".